# How can I use mssql functions on php? I don't have php_mssql.dll in my extensions folder

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, xampp

I'm trying to use SQL Server with PHP but I don't know how to install this feature. I have enabled extension=php_mssql.dll in my php.ini file but after restarting apache I got a error message saying that don't found the DLL file.

After much attempts I reinstalled XAMPP 1.81, and I'm starting now from zero.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question does not belong here.

Comment: Your comment is very helpfull

Comment: If you want help, please clarify what you're trying to ask. Do you have that DLL file? Is it compatible with your WAMP stack? Is it in the proper place? StackOverflow won't do your homework. It'll help and expand your knowledge if you tell it exactly what you want and what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** MSSQL has been discontinued as of 5.3

I believe the correct driver is `php_sqlsrv.dll`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php

Here are the available functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php

Comment: Microsoft links to drivers are broken. But I found in other sites. If this solve my problem I come back to check your post as answer. Thank you!

Comment: @JoaoPaulo http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php, select the appropriate version corresponding to your PHP version.

Comment: sqlsrv allow sqlsrv functions, but in my project i have mssql functions like mssql_connect, not sqlsrv_connect.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo I see now that MSSQL has been discontinued, meaning SQLSRV is the new replacement as of 5.3. So unless you go back to an earlier PHP version you may have to refactor your code.

Comment: Thank you. I'm installing an OLD version of PHP to do this. I think that I'll solve.